# Progressive web app ios push notifications?

Tags: progressive-web-apps

I noticed some blogs mentioned PWA works with IOS .. I have tried ' add to home screen and push notifications are not working ..please help me with sample demo.

Answer (score 1):

In iOS 11.3, Apple included Service Worker. That's why everybody is saying that PWAs work on iOS. But unfortunately there is currently no way to send Push Notifications to a PWA running on an iOS device. Also the user needs to manually add the PWA to the home screen.

See: https://medium.com/@firt/progressive-web-apps-on-ios-are-here-d00430dee3a7

Answer (score 0):

Apple is still lagging behind everyone here, even though they have had an add to homescreen functionality since 2007.

That is the answer to the add to homescreen. You need to use the mobile-web-app-capable, touch icons META tags to drive the iOS add to homescreen experience.

As for push, you will need to fallback, remember these progressively enhanced websites.

My fallback recommendation is SMS (Twilio is a good service for this).

Unfortunately, or maybe we are fortunate LOL, iOS does not support web push either.